# SWT Drag and Drop not working on Windows 10 in exported Eclipse RCP exe

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt, eclipse-rcp

I've been using Drag and Drop in my Eclipse RCP GUI plugin project for several years and have upgraded to Windows 10 Home recently. I have a widget that just sets itself up as a file drop listener using this code:

```
    Transfer[] transfers = new Transfer[] { FileTransfer.getInstance() };
    int ops = DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_MOVE;
    DropTarget target = new DropTarget(this, ops);
    target.setTransfer(transfers);
    target.addDropListener(new DropTargetAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
            if (event.data instanceof String[]) {
                List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
                String[] paths = (String[]) event.data;     
                for (String path : paths) {
                    File file = new File(path);
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        Iterator<File> recursive = FileUtils.iterateFiles(file, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
                        while (recursive.hasNext()) {
                            files.add(recursive.next());
                        }
                    } else {
                        files.add(file);
                    }
                }
                notifyListeners(files);                 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void dragEnter(final DropTargetEvent event)
        {
            log.error(event.detail+"");
            event.detail = DND.DROP_COPY;
        }
    });
```

Now in my new Win 10 environment when i run the application from Eclipse (my dev environment) the DnD works and the log get's my test error message. When I use the Export Product Wizard and run the resulting exe the DnD doesn't work, what I get is the cursor showing that I cannot drop my files on to my widget and there's no errors being written to the log from the dragEnter method.

The only thing I have to go on is that the export works if I run it on a Windows 7 PC but no on the Win 10 if that could possibly be the cause?

Comment: I can successfully drop a FileTransfer in our RCP application on a Windows 10 Pro system, using code that is very similar. One difference is that our extension of DropTargetAdapter also implements TransferDropTargetListener. Not sure if that matters. Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger on a Windows 10 system? Does your `drop()` method get entered at all?

Comment: It works when I run it from it eclipse, only when I export to an exe does it then not work.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, you said that. In those unusual situations, it can be useful to add some temporary debug prints or log messages to show at least how far the code is getting when run outside the development environment. If you're writing log messages, be sure to write a message type that passes through any logging constraints.

Comment: Yeah I've done that too. The drop() isn't being invoked and I wouldn't expect it to be since the cursor shows the drop isn't valid. The dragEnter method isn't being invoked either, so it's like something is happening in SWT before getting to my code and I don't know how to start tracing that.

Comment: did you solve your problem? What was the cause?

Comment: Still haven't. oddly it seems to be related to where it's ran from in win 10, if the exe is in program files under it's own folder, the DnD doesn't work, if it's ran from my user area it works fine.

Comment: Is the problem still there?

Comment: I don't believe so @D